# about "interior" excluded points in a region being boundary points.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

how can an excluded point in a region considered to be a boundary point.
Context: I was solving a question asking whether all of complex plane excluding a finite number of points is open or closed. the solution assumed the excluded points to be boundary points.
But I cannot understand these points to be conforming to the definition of being boundary points, I cannot find any point in the neighbourhood of these excluded points not belonging to the set.
Please explain what am I missing.

Clarification: the excluded point I am referring to are like point holes inside the region, not to be confused with the boundary of a disc. Also I think this concept would apply to any finite region, not only the whole complex plane.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have an open region $R\subset\Bbb C$ and a finite subset $F$ of $R$ and you want to know why is it that $F$ is a subset of the boundary of $R\setminus F$. Is that your question?

Comment: What definition of "boundary point" are you using?

Comment: a boundary point of a set is a point whose neighbourhood contains some points within and atleast one point without the set.

Comment: Well, neighborhoods of a point contain the point. If the point isn't itself contained in $R\backslash F$, then its neighborhoods certainly contain a point outside $R\backslash F$.

Comment: well when we consider all points of an open disc we consider all of them to be interior points because of the logic that we can find infinitely many points between the point in question and the "excluded " boundary of the outer circle. But why doesn't the same logic work in this case?

Comment: That's not what an interior point is. You should look up your definition of interior points again. A point which isn't even contained in a given set can't possibly be an interior point. It's in the name: interior points have to be inside the set of which they are interior points.

Comment: I don't think you got what I said, We consider an open disc as an open set containing all its interior points, that means the points infinitely near the excluded "boundary". For that we use the logic that even for points very near the boundary we can always find a small enough neighbourhood because there are infinite points between them.